# Roslaunch not found error when executing ros noetic project built and installed with custom snap (using snapcraft tool)

Tags: snap, ros, debug

So I have this multi-package ros project that I want to build with snapcraft so I can distribute it to client and update it easier. However, I managed to build it but for some reason the app cannot find the roslaunch command. I use a script (ros_start_script) to choose which nodes I want to launch. Heres the snapcraft.yaml file where I source the git containing the entire ros project, the start-script since it cannot find it otherwise, poetry since the project uses it and creates an app to launch the script :

```
name: ss-delivery-robot
version: '1.0'
summary: ROS software for Sirsteward delivery robots
description: |
  This snap package provides the SS Delivery Robot ROS repository.

confinement: devmode
base: core20

parts:
  ss-delivery-robot:
    plugin: catkin
    source-type: git
    source: https://christopherlajoie@bitbucket.org/sirsteward/ss_delivery_robot.git
    #source: git@bitbucket.org:sirsteward/ss_delivery_robot.git
    source-branch: feature/snapcraft
    stage-packages:
      - ros-noetic-rosbash # for rosrun
      - ros-noetic-roslaunch # for roslaunch

  start-script:
    plugin: dump
    source: https://christopherlajoie@bitbucket.org/sirsteward/ss_delivery_robot.git
    source-branch: feature/snapcraft
    organize:
      ros_start_script.sh: bin/

  poetry:
    plugin: python
    python-packages: [poetry]
    stage-packages:
      - libyaml-cpp-dev

apps:
  ros-start-script:
    command: bin/ros_start_script.sh
    plugs: [network, network-bind]
    extensions: [ ros1-noetic ]
```

And here's the content of the script with the roslaunch line that causes the error :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

#sleep 90

# setup ros environment
source "/home/$USER/ROS_PROJECT/devel/setup.bash"
cd "/home/$USER/ROS_PROJECT/src/ss_delivery_robot/"
source ".env"
if [[ "$MODULES_SELECTOR" == "True" ]]; then
  source "robot_modules_selection.sh"
fi
source ".env"
dt=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')

if [[ "$ENVIRONMENT" != *"DEBUG"* ]]; then
  poetry run roslaunch node_manager_pkg node_manager.launch timestamp:=$dt
fi

exec "$@"
```

The later is launched after succesfully building the snap project, installing it and executing it with the command `ss-delivery-robot.ros-start-script`

I found this helpful website but even after going trough it I cannot fix my bug : https://ubuntu.com/robotics/docs/faq-and-troubleshooting